# standardising sub-data sets, such that the whole dataset is standardised

Tags: normalization

Consider a data set $X$ made up of smaller subsets:
$X=A \cup B \cup C$, with $A,B,C$ disjoint data sets.
Eg: 
$A=\{1.0, -1.0, 0\}$, 
$B=\{5.0, -7.0, 2.0\}$, 
$C=\{1.5, -5.0, 8.0\}$

Is is possible to transform (scale, shift) $A,B,C$ such that each is individually standardised to have  mean=0, and  std dev=1.0,
and so that $X$ also has mean=0, std dev=1.0?

Comment: You might get some strange answers to this question because it conflates *standardized* (having zero mean and unit standard deviation) with *normal*.  People will point out that $X$ itself cannot possibly be normally distributed (for one thing, it's a discrete finite set of values) and that if you mean for $X$ to become *approximately* normally distributed, even achieving that will generally be impossible via only changes of scale and location. So what are you really asking--is your question about standardization or is it truly about normal distributions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is both 'no, you can't' and 'well, yes, *sort of*' -- it depends on how strict you want to be about things.

Once you standardize the subgroups there are no degrees of freedom left in linear transformations to do anything about the overall variable, so you're stuck with whatever that achieves.  However, the situation isn't necessarily bad, it depends on what you need.

The mean is no issue, that works simply by standardizing the subgroups.

It cannot be achieved exactly for the usual [Bessel-corrected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) standard deviation (the [$n-1$ denominator version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation)). It will only approximately apply - but in large samples, the approximation is very good. In small samples like your example with three groups of 3, it's not so good.

It's not possible in general to simultaneously standardize the subgroups and the whole sample, because making the individual subgroup standard deviations exactly $1$ relies on dividing by $n_i-1$ (the degrees of freedom).

This means that the sums of squared deviations (from $0$, since they're already standardized) for each subgroup is $n_i-1$, so when you sum the squared deviations for all standardized subgroups concatenated into one single group, their sum of squares is $N-g$, where $g$ is the number of groups and $N=\sum_{i=1}^g n_i$.

This means for the overall variable, the usual Bessel-corrected standard deviation will be $\sqrt{\frac{N-g}{N-1}}\approx 1-\frac{g}{2N}$. In your problem that's $\sqrt{\frac{9-3}{9-1}}=\sqrt{0.75}\approx 0.866$ (the $1-\frac{g}{2N}$  approximation gives $0.833$). That's a fair way short of 1.

*If* you used the [$n$-denominator version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) of standard deviation for both the subgroups and the overall variable, then it works "automatically" - you get the overall variable standardized for free.

So if you want both standardized you must settle for it being only approximate in not-too-small samples, or you must settle for defining standard deviation as the $n$-denominator form.

Edit: it seems from your comments that your sample sizes are very large (on the order of 200 per subgroup or so) so the effect will be very small. For most people the small difference from 1 will be of little consequence in that situation.

Comment: My actual dataset is about 20,000 and i would break it up into less than 100 subsets, so that gives me a bessel-corrected std deviation of >0.9975.
Should I edit my question to reflect this?

Comment: No need to edit the question; I think the discussion of your question in the small sample case is broadly useful even if it doesn't relate to your needs. I'll add an edit that relates to your comment.

Comment: Is the n-denominator form the regular, high-school stats form? I can't find any reference to what the n-denominator form is on w quick google.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation

Comment: "The sums of squared deviations (from 0, since they're already standardized) for each subgroup is $n_i−1$, so when you sum the squared deviations for all standardized subgroups concatenated into one single group, their sum of squares is $N−g$." Is this correct? The (squared) deviations from the mean of a standardised subset are likely to be much smaller than the deviations from the mean of the whole data set — consider the subset $\{-1, -1, -1\}$ of an otherwise standardised data set. You can't just add them to get the squared deviations for the entire set.

Comment: The discussion in the answer is about *first* standardizing the subsets (centered, then scaled) before considering the overall set. Every subset (after centering) has sum 0, and so the overall set has sum 0. So in the strategy under discussion, your example subset $\{-1,-1,-1\}$ would be centered to $\{0,0,0\}$ individually *first*. (In that particular case you can't make its s.d. 1, but with continuous variables that has probability 0.)

Comment: Can you clarify the answer? I'm not seeing how this is actually to be done. Are you suggesting the whole thing must be standardised again after? (cos I can't do that.)

Comment: No, the point of the answer (and it's explicitly stated there) is once you standardize the subgroups, there's nothing more you *can* do. But (and this is dealt with extensively in the rest of the answer) this doesn't matter very much; the overall mean is zero and the overall standard deviation is close to 1.